# gcc compile with 32-bit architecture not working

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

I am trying to compile a C file with gcc. The code in header file will need specified architecture in order to compile.

```
#if defined( _8BIT_ARCHITECTURE )
 #include "type8.h"

#elif defined( _16BIT_ARCHITECTURE )
 #include "type16.h"

#elif defined( _32BIT_ARCHITECTURE )
 #include "type32.h"

#else
 #error ARCHITECTURE not defined
#endif
```

When using Visual Studio, I can configure the platform into 32-bit and it can build successfully. But how do I do the same thing with gcc commands?

I was trying to use:

```
gcc -m32 -c myFile.c -I /somePath/
```

But it keeps giving me the error statement:

```
 #error ARCHITECTURE not defined
```

Comment: "32-bit architecture" is not well defined. What specific characteristic do you want to use? A processor may have variations in bus width, general register width, instruction size, integer widths supported in arithmetic units, and more. A C implementation may have a 32-bit `int` with a 32-bit `long` or a 64-bit `long`, as well as other possibilities. To illuminate your question, explain why you need to define types differently for different architectures.

Comment: Those `_XXXX_ARCHITECTURE` defines do not appear to be standard ones. It would be worth working out where those are set in the VS build as it will probably guide you on how to set them for gcc for your context.

Comment: @EricPostpischil in the types file, they defined data structures for different architectures.

Comment: @WeiGong: That is not enough information. Are the structures using different types based on their widths so the structure layouts are the same regardless of the target architecture? Or are they doing something else?

Comment: If you add `-D_32BIT_ARCHITECTURE` to your compile command it should get you past the current error and potentially open up the next can of worms.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I just want to compile the file through the cmd line. It is a Dev Ops work and the C code itself works well. I am not familiar with C code and this project. They can be compiled with Visual Studio under 32-bit configuration. I just want to find a way to compile it in Command Prompt

Comment: @WeiGong: Just getting something to compile does not mean it works. The original code you show was likely customizing some type aliases to known types in various target environments. But a `long` can have different widths in different “32-bit environments”. So you should not just be kludging some preprocessor definition to get the compilation to complete without errors. You ought to be investigating what the header files define and why and how to match them to the GCC environment you want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `-D_32BIT_ARCHITECTURE` fix the issue